# Spark Dataframe column with last character of other column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to get the last character from a string in a dataframe column and place it into another column.

I have a Spark dataframe that looks like this:

```
    animal
    ======
    cat
    mouse
    snake
```

I want something like this:

```
    lastchar
    ========
    t
    e
    e
```

Right now I can do this with a UDF that looks like:

```
    def get_last_letter(animal):
        return animal[-1]

    get_last_letter_udf = udf(get_last_letter, StringType())

    df.select(get_last_letter_udf("animal").alias("lastchar")).show()
```

I'm mainly curious if there's a better way to do this without a UDF. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use the substring function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
df.withColumn("b", substring(col("columnName"), -1, 1))
```

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't thought of trying a negative number for substring. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get everything but the first and last character? `df.withColumn("b", substring(col("columnName"), 1, -1))` doesn't work.

Comment: @citynorman You can try to use regex_extract to get it by regex. Substring needs a constant number of elements (the -1 trick can be used for start position, not length)

Answer (score 4):

One way is by using Column substr() function:

`df = df.withColumn("lastchar", df.animal.substr(-1,1))`

See documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be with the "expr" function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("lastchar", expr('RIGHT(animal, 1)')).show()
```