# substring multiple characters from the last index of a pyspark string column using negative indexing

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Closely related to: [Spark Dataframe column with last character of other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512884/spark-dataframe-column-with-last-character-of-other-column/45513496?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
 but I want to extract multiple characters from the `-1` index.

---

I have the following pyspark dataframe `df`

```
+----------+----------+
|    number|event_type|
+----------+----------+
|0342224022|        11|
|0112964715|        11|
+----------+----------+
```

I want to extract 3 characters from the last index of the `number` column.

I tried the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring 
df.select(substring(df['number'], -1, 3), 'event_type').show(2)

# which returns:

+----------------------+----------+
|substring(number,-1,3)|event_type|
+----------------------+----------+
|                     2|        11|
|                     5|        11|
+----------------------+----------+
```

The below is the expected output (and I'm not sure what the output above is):

```
+----------------------+----------+
|substring(number,-1,3)|event_type|
+----------------------+----------+
|                   022|        11|
|                   715|        11|
+----------------------+----------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** Spark version 1.6.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how you use [`substring`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring). Your position will be -3 and the length is 3.

```python
pyspark.sql.functions.substring(str, pos, len)
```

You need to change your substring function call to:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
df.select(substring(df['number'], -3, 3), 'event_type').show(2)
#+------------------------+----------+
#|substring(number, -3, 3)|event_type|
#+------------------------+----------+
#|                     022|        11|
#|                     715|        11|
#+------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Shouldn't the position be -1, as per the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=lo#pyspark.sql.functions.substring I'm currently on mobile. I will update once I have access to a computer.

Comment: You need to specify the starting position, and then the length till which you want to look at. So starting from position -3, look for 3 string characters.

Comment: My starting position should be the last index. I didn't get how the last index of a string became -3 instead of -1

Comment: You're talking about reverse numbers. Please try the solution and then tell me if it gives you the desired output. You'll understand yourself.

Comment: You want last 3 numbers, right? You can't count the length in reverse. You need to specify a starting position, which will be -3 which is first character from the last 3 numbers. And then you look for 3 characters from that position.

Comment: Yes, this works. Your third comment was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @pissall is it possible to extract the first characters excluding the last 3 .. is that suppose to be substring(string,1,-3) does not seem to work

Comment: @EB You need to specify index and length. `-3` is not a length. Do you have variable or fixed length of the items you want to sub?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with SQL code thanks to "expr" function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.select(expr('RIGHT(number, 3) AS substring'), 'event_type').show(2)
```

Comment: This is a much better option.