# Group by hour in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe which contain time column which is in string format.

dataframe=

```
      time         value
      00:00:00      10
      00:23:00      5
      00:59:00      23 
      01:23:34      34
      01:56:00      34
```

Every time i try to group by hours on Time column it give output like below this :-

```
 hour    count
  0       38
  1       68
```

But I want Out put like this..

```
 hour    count
  00       38
  01       68
```

For this i wrote the query like below ;-

```
    dataframe.groupBy(hour('time')).agg({'value':'count'})
```

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve sum instead of count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [substring multiple characters from the last index of a pyspark string column using negative indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793479/substring-multiple-characters-from-the-last-index-of-a-pyspark-string-column-usi/49793592#49793592)

Since your time column is in `StringType`, we can use `substring` to get the hour as you want, and group on it as `StringType`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, col

df = df.withColumn("hour", substring(F.col("time"), 0, 2))
group_df = df.groupby("hour").sum("value") # or whichever aggregation you want
```