# Mask/replace inner part of string column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have an email column in a dataframe and I want to replace part of it with asterisks. I am unable to figure it out using PySpark functions.

My email column could be something like this"

```
email_col
abc123@gmail.com
123abc123@yahoo.com
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
mod_email_col
ab**23@gmail.com
12*****23@yahoo.com
```

So essentially apart from the 1st 2 characters and the last 2 characters, I want the remaining part to be replaced by asterisks.

This is what I tried

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

split_email = F.split(df.email_address, "@")
df = df.withColumn('email_part', split_email.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('start', df.email_part.substr(0,2))
df = df.withColumn('end', df.email_part.substr(-2,2))

df.withColumn(
    'masked_part', 
     F.expr("regexp_replace(email_part, email_part[email_part.index(start)+len(start):email_part.index(end)], '*')")
).show(n=5)
```

Comment: You should split the string at `@` and then have a look at my answer: [substring multiple characters from the last index of a pyspark string column using negative indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793479/substring-multiple-characters-from-the-last-index-of-a-pyspark-string-column-usi/49793592#49793592)

Comment: I tried all of that. But I am unable to figure out how extract going from the 1st 2 and then up to the last 2. I did the split to get the part before the domain of course. Updated with code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with the help of following regular expression: `(?<=.{2})\w+(?=.{2}@)`

- `(?<=.{2})`: Positive lookbehind for 2 characters
- `\w+`: Any word characters
- `(?=.{2}@)`: Positive lookahead for 2 characters followed by a literal `@`

First use [`regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) to extract this pattern from your string.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, regexp_replace

df = df.withColumn(
    "pattern", 
    regexp_extract("email", r"(?<=.{2})\w+(?=.{2}@)", 0)
)
df.show()
#+-------------------+-------+
#|              email|pattern|
#+-------------------+-------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|     c1|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|  3abc1|
#|      abcd@test.com|       |
#+-------------------+-------+
```

Then use [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) to create a replacement of `*` of the same length.

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "replacement",
    regexp_replace("pattern", r"\w", "*")
)
df.show()
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+
#|              email|pattern|replacement|
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|     c1|         **|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|  3abc1|      *****|
#|      abcd@test.com|       |           |
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+
```

Next use `regexp_replace` again on the original `email` column using the derived `pattern` and `replacement` columns.

To be safe, [`concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) the lookbehind/lookaheads from the original pattern when doing the replacment. To do this, we will have to use [`expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) in order to [pass the column values as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, expr, lit

df = df.withColumn(
    "mod_email_col",
    expr("regexp_replace(email, concat('(?<=.{2})', pattern, '(?=.{2}@)'), replacement)")
)
df.show()
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
#|              email|pattern|replacement|      mod_email_col|
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|     c1|         **|   ab**23@gmail.com|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|  3abc1|      *****|12*****23@yahoo.com|
#|      abcd@test.com|       |           |      abcd@test.com|
#+-------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Finally drop the intermediate columns:

```
df = df.drop("pattern", "replacement")
df.show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|              email|      mod_email_col|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|   ab**23@gmail.com|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|12*****23@yahoo.com|
#|      abcd@test.com|      abcd@test.com|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Note**: I added one test case to show that this does nothing if the email address part is 4 characters or less.

---

**Update**: Here are some ways you can handle edge cases where the email address part is less than 4 characters.

The rules I am using:

- Email address length is more than 5: do the above
- Email address length is 3, 4, or 5: keep the first and last characters, masking the others with `*`
- Email address is length 1 or 2: mask single the character before the `@`

Code:

```
patA = "regexp_replace(email, concat('(?<=.{2})', pattern, '(?=.{2}@)'), replacement)"
patB = "regexp_replace(email, concat('(?<=.{1})', pattern, '(?=.{1}@)'), replacement)"

from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, regexp_replace
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, expr, length, lit, split, when

df.withColumn("address_part", split("email", "@").getItem(0))\
.withColumn(
    "pattern", 
    when(
        length("address_part") > 5, 
        regexp_extract("email", r"(?<=.{2})\w+(?=.{2}@)", 0)
    ).otherwise(
        regexp_extract("email", r"(?<=.{1})\w+(?=.{1}@)", 0)
    )
).withColumn(
    "replacement", regexp_replace("pattern", r"\w", "*")
).withColumn(
    "mod_email_col",
    when(
        length("address_part") > 5, expr(patA)
    ).when(
        length("address_part") > 3, expr(patB)
    ).otherwise(regexp_replace('email', '\w(?=@)', '*'))
).drop("pattern", "replacement", "address_part").show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|              email|      mod_email_col|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|   ab**23@gmail.com|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|12*****23@yahoo.com|
#|     abcde@test.com|     a***e@test.com|
#|      abcd@test.com|      a**d@test.com|
#|        ab@test.com|        a*@test.com|
#|         a@test.com|         *@test.com|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: wow, this is beautiful. Thank you so much! What if I want to include the one with just 4 characters, so like take the 1st and the last character and replace the between?

Comment: @ManasJani in that case use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to check the length of the replacement string. If its > 0 do this, otherwise use a different pattern (without testing I think it's as simple as changing the `{2}`s to `{1}`s. You'll also have to handle the case where the email is only 2 characters long..

Comment: So if I want to keep it dynamic then I would have to use the when condition sort of thing?

Comment: @ManasJani I posted an update to handle your edge cases

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really helped me understand regex better. How do I pass a function argument to the expressions above? like `def mask_email(df, email_col):` ? I am getting an error when I pass a value to the `email_col` arg.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simplified using some string manipulations(Spark SQL functions: [instr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#instr), concat, [left](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#left), [repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#repeat), [substr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#substr)):

First find the position of the `@` in the email string: `pos_at = instr(email_col, '@')`, then the length of the username part is `pos_at - 1`. If we take `N=2` as the number of chars to be kept, then the number of chars to be masked should be `pos_at - 1 - 2*N`, in the code, we have:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import instr, expr

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(e,) for e in ['abc123@gmail.com', '123abc123@yahoo.com', 'abd@gmail.com']]
      , ['email_col']
)

# set N=2 as a parameter in the SQL expression
N = 2

df.withColumn('pos_at', instr('email_col', '@')) \
  .withColumn('new_col', expr("""
        CONCAT(LEFT(email_col,{0}), REPEAT('*', pos_at-1-2*{0}), SUBSTR(email_col, pos_at-{0}))
   """.format(N))).show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------+------+-------------------+
#|email_col          |pos_at|new_col            |
#+-------------------+------+-------------------+
#|abc123@gmail.com   |7     |ab**23@gmail.com   |
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|10    |12*****23@yahoo.com|
#|abd@gmail.com      |4     |abbd@gmail.com     |
#+-------------------+------+-------------------+
```

Notice the issue with the last row when `pos_at - 1 <= 2*N`, which has to be processed separately. If I define the following logic:

```
if `pos_at - 1 <= 2*N`:   keep the first char and mask the rest
otherwise: keep the original processing routine
```

the whole processing can be wrapped up in a lambda function with two arguments (`column_name` and `N`)

```
# in the SQL expression, {0} is column_name and {1} is N
mask_email = lambda col_name, N: expr("""

  IF(INSTR({0}, '@') <= {1}*2+1
    , CONCAT(LEFT({0},1), REPEAT('*', INSTR({0}, '@')-2), SUBSTR({0}, INSTR({0}, '@')))
    , CONCAT(LEFT({0},{1}), REPEAT('*', INSTR({0}, '@')-1-2*{1}), SUBSTR({0}, INSTR({0}, '@')-{1}))
  ) as `{0}_masked`

""".format(col_name, N))

df.select('*', mask_email('email_col', 2)).show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|          email_col|   email_col_masked|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|   abc123@gmail.com|   ab**23@gmail.com|
#|123abc123@yahoo.com|12*****23@yahoo.com|
#|      abd@gmail.com|      a**@gmail.com|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
```